# Angular router can't match routes after update (v14 -> v17)

Tags: angular, router, angular-routing, angular17, angular-upgrade

Since the Angular update from version 14 to 15, we have had the problem that our nested router no longer finds the routes, which should obviously be there when the routing is triggered by a click in the application. However, if you call up the route via the URL, it can be found.  We then went up to version 17 because we hoped that the problem might be fixed with a higher version. Unfortunately, this was not the case. For this reason, we have created a minimal version of the application in which the error is still reproducible.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/ingoher/angularrouterissue) (Link is only working when copy & pasted or after page reload for some reason)

Step by step:

- Step 1: Call route /orders/create/type
- Step 2: Click on the button (red rectangle)
- Step 3: See console.log (Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'orders/create/address')
- Step 4: Enter the route /orders/create/address in the url and call it up
- Step 5: The route is called successfully

Comment: the link is not working

Comment: @JSmith try [this link](https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/ingoher/angularrouterissue)

Comment: For whatever reason the link does not work when you navigate there via Stack Overflow. If you reload the "Page not found" page with F5, it works.

Comment: why are you still using modules?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by modules? Unfortunately, I also don't have any more detailed information about why some settings are the way they are, as these decisions were made before I started in the project.

Comment: @IngoH I would suggest you tidy and refactor the project before going any further.then use `router.navigate(['/my/route']);`.It's honestly a mess.

Comment: Unfortunately, the project is too big for us to refactor it quickly. We need a solution with the current circumstances

Comment: try to refactor at least the fact that your components are now standalone and try remove as much modules as possible.How many project files do you have approximately.I think an angular script exist to do that automatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257236/discussion-between-jsmith-and-ingoh).